# i am not able to import a package from another directory to main.go

Tags: go

while i tried adding **import config "./config"** in main.go and try to save it and run then it remove the **import config "./"** section

my code structure is

-config/config.go

model/model.go

main.go
while running i got

[go] can't load package: package .: found packages config (config.go) and main (main.go) in /Users/Desktop/inventory-backend

Comment: If you have not already done so, read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).  The document covers the basics of organizing packages in a workspace and importing those packages.

Answer (score 0):

In go we import modules by specifying the path as e.g.

`import "gopath/projectName/config"`